# Creating accurate line buffer in ESRI Javascript API

Tags: javascript, geometry, buffer, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm using the ESRI JavaScript API v3.8. (I know 3.11 is out - can't upgrade yet.)

What I'm trying to do is to create a geometric buffer of a size provided by the user from an arbitrary line (or point) selected by the user. Some of the relevant code is shown below:

```
var params = new esri.tasks.BufferParameters();
params.distances = [values.distance]; //the input distance                  
params.geometries = [gr.geometry]; //the input geometry
params.unit = esri.tasks.GeometryService.UNIT_FOOT;
params.outSpatialReference = mapView.map.spatialReference; //always 3857
params.bufferSpatialReference = gr.geometry.spatialReference; //always 3857

esri.config.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push('mydomain.com');
esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = 'https://serverdomain.com/proxy';

var gsvc = new esri.tasks.GeometryService('https://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer');                   

gsvc.simplify(params.geometries, function(geometries){
    params.geometries = geometries;                     
    gsvc.buffer(params, function(geometries){
        //add output geometry to the map and perform spatial query with it                                                  
    }, function(err){
        //handle error
    });                 

}, function(err){
    //handle error
});
```

The problem is that, if I use an input distance of 500 (feet), then measure the distance from the center line of the input geometry on `self._queryGeometry`, using ESRI's measurement tool, the actual width of the polygon created is something like 370 feet on either side of the center line.

I've managed to get this to work more accurately using the Illinois State Plane spatial reference, as my test objects are in Illinois, but the logic needs to work *everywhere*.

When I try various incarnations of doing a geodesic buffer, the input distance unit seems to get ignored and, using an input distance value of 500, I get a buffer that spans the entire world! Either that or the results are exactly the same, depending on how things are set up.

I believe I need to do a geodesic buffer, but I have absolutely no idea how to go about that in such a way that the geometry service will actually pay attention to the units I'm sending in.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I've left anything out.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there might be a spatial reference issue somewhere.  You can try re-projecting geometry into 3857 if that's what the map is and I would inspect the geometry being returned from the buffer and simplify to make sure it looks like what your expecting.  I have had issues with the geometry service area's and length's returning slightly incorrect geometries and in my case it ended up being an issue with an incorrect spatial reference.  Also, I know you said you can't upgrade, but 3.13 is out and can do geometry options locally without the need for a proxy or any network requests, if possible, it would be worth trying out.